# concurrent transfer task limit on WebDAV server

Tags: webdav

I've built up WebDAV server based on  ITHitWebDAVServerEngine,  Could you help tell me how to get the number of concurrent transfer tasks ?  and limit the maximum of concurrent uploading? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you built server based on IIS then you should use IIS tools for this.
But if your server is based on HttpListener class then please use possibilities of this class.